# Spring Boot not allowing POST requests to static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-post

I have a spring boot web application that uses an Angular 2 frontend. I have the Angular 2 frontend all located in the `/static/` directory on my classpath when I build my application so that spring boot serves it all up as static resources.

My application uses SAML 2.0 to authenticate against an IdP, and when the IdP returns to my application after authenticating, it sends a POST request in order to post the SAML response.

This results in a **405 - Method Not Allowed**.

Is there any way to allow POST requests to static resources with spring boot?

I even attempted to add a controller that would accept POST requests and simply forward the request to the root of my application to the proper view, index.html.

I added the following properties in my application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

And added the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

But to no avail. Spring boot still internally resolved my request to the statically served resource which does not allow POST requests. Here are the relevant debug messages from spring:

```
2017-03-22 12:20:56.261 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:865 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/notification-service/]
2017-03-22 12:20:56.261 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /
2017-03-22 12:20:56.262 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:317 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.papajohns.corporate.notification.controller.IndexController.index()]
2017-03-22 12:20:56.262 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'indexController'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.262 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:85 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2017-03-22 12:20:56.263 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor:71 - Skip CORS processing: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
2017-03-22 12:20:56.268 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:263 - Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-03-22 12:20:56.268 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.view.BeanNameViewResolver:74 - No matching bean found for view name 'index'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.269 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.view.BeanNameViewResolver:74 - No matching bean found for view name 'index.html'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.269 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1670 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'index'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.269 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.270 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.274 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1670 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'index.html'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.274 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.274 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.275 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:338 - Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'index'; URL [/static/index.html]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.276 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1265 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'index'; URL [/static/index.html]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.278 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.view.InternalResourceView:166 - Forwarding to resource [/static/index.html] in InternalResourceView 'index'
2017-03-22 12:20:56.279 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:865 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/notification-service/static/index.html]
2017-03-22 12:20:56.280 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /static/index.html
2017-03-22 12:20:56.282 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Did not find handler method for [/static/index.html]
2017-03-22 12:20:56.282 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:190 - Matching patterns for request [/static/index.html] are [/**]
2017-03-22 12:20:56.282 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:219 - URI Template variables for request [/static/index.html] are {}
2017-03-22 12:20:56.282 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:140 - Mapping [/static/index.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@77392aa5]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-03-22 12:20:56.283 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor:71 - Skip CORS processing: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
2017-03-22 12:20:56.292 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1044 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-03-22 12:20:56.292 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2017-03-22 12:20:56.294 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:110 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2017-03-22 12:20:56.295 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2017-03-22 12:20:56.295 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2017-03-22 12:20:56.295 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter:104 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@27aca4f4
2017-03-22 12:20:56.295 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter:206 - Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf as a dependency, then moving the `index.html` out of `/static/` and into `/templates/`. I removed the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` properties from my application.properties, as spring boot thymeleaf will automatically look for `.html` templates in `/templates/`. After doing that, my `index.html` was no longer being served as a static resource by spring, and my `IndexController` (same one as shown in the original question) properly handles my POST request and renders the "index" view, which properly displays my `index.html`.

Comment: I have similar issue. I need to get static content through POST request. I cannot use thymeleaf as I'm migrating an old spring app to Spring Boot. Any idea ?